# Internalise strings in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I accidently externalised all my strings in an eclipse java project a week ago. However I cant find  any option to revert this? Is there a way to convert externalised strings like `mstring = Messages.getString("VSsimpleCursorAdapter.0")` to `"mstring = This is the string"` as a batch? I'm looking for a python or ruby script that can do it automagiclly.

Comment: Not that I know of.  You can revert the classes from your local history.  Sounds painful tho.

Comment: time to start using source code control systems :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Comment: Do you have them externalized into one message.properties file, or several?

Comment: Maybe you can use `Replace with > Local History ...` from file context menu if there is such history stored and there is not so many files you need to revert ;-)

Comment: @s.d  just one. Is there a way?

Comment: @Betlista sadly that's not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An awesome oneliner from @potong

```
sed 's|^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)|s@Messages.getString("\1")@"\2"@g|;s/\\/\\\\/g' messages.properties | sed -i -f - *.java
```

Run this inside your src dir, and see the magic.

Answer (score 1):

'Source > Externalize strings', and then use the 'Internalize' option on the strings you want to internalize.

Comment: Did you select the project in package explorer and then invoke the action ?

Comment: Yes I did, only 3 new strings are listed. And they are not externalized yet. Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: In the wizard, uncheck 'Filter all existing ignored and externalized entries' (This option is located above the table)